# Are C keywords/functions not enclosed in std namespace in C++?

Tags: c++, std, backwards-compatibility

The following piece of code works fine on my local system but threw compile error on an online platform.

```
#include <iostream>

int32_t time[int32_t(1e5)];

int main()
{
    int32_t n;
    std::cin>>n;
    for(int32_t i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        int32_t temp;
        std::cin>>temp;
        --temp;
        ++time[temp];
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Complie Error Description]

Clearly, the error is generated because of line 3 `int32_t time[int32_t(1e5)];`
But, I am not able to understand why the compilation error occurred.

I have not included `ctime` or any such header and even have not unwrapped `std` namespace. But still, compilation failure occurred.

I have gcc 8.3.0 with __cplusplus 201703 on my system. Not sure what is the version on the online platform.

Comment: The error msg tells you the header include chain - starts from `iostream`.

Comment: That's why user C libraries prefix their names. You should avoid the names used by the standard at global scope.

Comment: Maybe online compiler version is up to date. GCC Version latest: 10.1 and latest c++ version is C++20.

Comment: @chrisThat's why I prefer not writing the line "using namespace std". So does that mean, C keywords are not put in std namespaces?

Comment: It's unfortunate but standard header files are allowed to include other standard declarations. So you can't rely on not declaring `time` just because you didn't `#include <ctime>`

Comment: Including `ctime` notwithstanding, you're also not including the proper header for `int32_t` (e.g. `cstdint`).

Comment: I think implementations are allowed to place C library definitions in the global namespace as well as the `std` namespace.

Comment: @john Can you provide some source? I am interested in reading about it

Comment: @WhozCraig Ok, I will take care of it from next time. But I don't think that is causing error in any way.

Comment: @deadLock https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header see the section 'C compatibility headers'

Comment: @deadLock, You can see in the error message that `time.h` is included. No std namespace for C headers, just the C++ versions, and even then it's not guaranteed that global names won't be defined as well.

Comment: @deadLock Just because you mention C, that does not mean that the question is about C. This is clearly a C++ question.

Comment: @klutt I got your point and I will not revert back it again. But at the time of asking, I believed the problem arose because of the backward compatibility of C++ with C, and that's why I added the tag 'C'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard says that when you include any standard include file it is possible that this will include other include files. It is implementation dependent which ones and how many of them.

The implication is that your code simply must not define any global name that is also standard.

I can understand this seems a difficult requirement (indeed it is) and also that makes one wonder why there are standard include files at all and we don't have simply the whole standard available instead (that's a good question). But none the less this is the situation.

Situation is even worse with POSIX where not only random names are reserved, but also quite a lot **prefixes** and **suffixes**; for example code that use any name **starting** with `LC_` followed by an uppercase letter in any way is possibly clashing with `#define`s related to locale support. Any name that ends with `_t` is also reserved, not joking. [The list is huge](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/xsh_chap02_02.html).

As a general rule try to define the least possible amount of global names and avoid anything that is also used by the standard library. Even when "it works" on your compiler, your program may find the problem when ported to another compiler (or the next version of the same compiler). Avoiding defining global names makes also easier for your code to be integrated in larger programs with code written by others. Ideally your code should just have one global name (a namespace, a single class or a single function)... unfortunately with C++ you cannot get below that.

Something I remember bumping in when writing small C++ experiments when I usually don't care about these name clashing problems is for example `y0` that is a standard Bessel function (this is not a joke; there is a global standard function `double y0(double)` and any program that uses `y0` for anything else at global level is not a valid C++ program).

Comment: I run the same code with 'time' as a local variable and it worked fine. **Can I be assured that there would be no problem with the name clashing if I declare variables in local space?** Because, for sure I would never be able to memorise all the reserved names.

Comment: @deadLock: names reserved as potentially macros are far less, so for local names the situation is much better. Indeed I think no one can remember the huge amount of reserved names prefixes and suffixes... that's why the general rules is just avoid the global namespace as much as possible.

Answer (score 6):

You include the header file `time.h` indirectly. In this header file there is a declaration of a function named `time` that is in conflict with your declaration.

Just change the variable `time` to another name (`time_1`).

Comment: The `time` in `<time.h>` is actually a declared function, not a variable.

Comment: @Peter hence why the error message says `time` is being redeclared as a different type of symbol.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Yes, I was aware of that.   When I typed the previous comment, however, I was not simply restating the obvious.  At that time - before a subsequent edit - this answer stated outright that the standard header `<time.h>` declared a variable named `time`.

Comment: @Peter Yes it is a  function declaration. I mean just  there is a same name that conflict.

Answer (score 3):

> Are C keywords/functions not enclosed in std namespace in C++?

Keywords (and also macros): No, those are not in namespaces.

Functions, types and variables (i.e. all identifiers except macros): Depends on which standard header you include.

If you include C standard header such as `<stdint.h>`, then the names will be in the global namespace. They may also be in the `std` namespace, but that is not guaranteed.

If you include the corresponding `<cstdint>` header, then the names from the C standard header are guaranteed to be in the `std` namespace. They may also be in the global namespace, but that is not guaranteed.

You've failed to include either `<stdint.h>` or `<cstdint>`, so there is no guarantee that `int32_t` would be declared in either namespace. But you've included another standard header and therefore there is no guarantee that it wouldn't be declared in some namespace - because standard headers may include other headers; you should never rely on such transitive inclusion (in the way that your example relies on it) unless documented in the standard.

Same applies to the `time` function. You've included a standard header and there is no guarantee that it wouldn't include another standard header which declares `time`. And there is no guarantee that it wouldn't be in the global namespace.

Regardless of whether you include any standard headers, all names used by the C standard library are reserved to the language implementation in the global namespace. By defining `::time` yourself, the behaviour of your program will be undefined (UB is allowed to fail compilation, which is the best outcome).

> Can I be assured that there would be no problem with the name clashing if I declare variables in local space?

In case of `time`, Yes. C standard names (except macros of course) are reserved only in the global namespace. Local names are not in the global namespace; they will shadow the global one, which is fine. It is also fine to define these in your own custom namespace.

Macro names, as well as certain identifiers such as those that include double underscore are reserved in all namespaces. All macro names are all upper case, so it is easy to avoid them by including lower case characters in names.

---

To avoid name conflicts with standard names, as well as third party libraries, one should only declare one name in the global namespace (besides `main`): A (hopefully unique) namespace that contains all other namespace scope declarations. And macros should be avoided when possible, but where necessary, they should include some (hopefully unique) prefix.